# Get indexes on a Doctrine Entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to get the sql column indexes on a specific Doctrine Entity without instantiating that entity?
I am looking to prevent people from making unindexed queries.

Comment: Can you please define *indexes* in the context of your question?

Comment: @A.L edited to reflect that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure regarding entity, but you can use [Doctrine Schema Manager](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html#listtableindexes) to list table indices